# Talend - no output from the tSalesForceInput component

Tags: salesforce, etl, talend

I am new to Talend and I have a very simple task of bringing in a Salesforce "contact" table into the database. To begin with testing, I only have the tSalesforceInput and tLogRow components (as per screenshot - left activated sub job) and I am only selecting "accountId" in the SOQL.

```
"SELECT AccountId
 FROM contact
 WHERE AccountId != null
 LIMIT 1000"
```

This returns a log output of 1000 AccountIds fine (as in screenshot - below).

I then introduced the tConvertType component (as per screenshot - right activated sub job) and I lost all output (log output returns 1000 rows with null values). I did not introduce any datatype casting in the convert component yet.

Would really appreciate some inputs on what could be happening. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually making a mistake of not selecting the "cast" method in the tConvertType component properties. I selected "Auto Cast" here and then in the "Edit schema" option, changed datatypes to what I want. Newbie mistakes :)

[image]